# how to do floating point arithmetic without using float

Tags: floating-point-conversion

In our processor,float is not allowed(u32 or int data type is allowed).Implementation needs the floating point addition,how addition of two real numbers can be done without using float?

Answer (score 0):

You could fake it with a struct, something like what's described [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=bI8w17SyNdYC&pg=PA268&lpg=PA268&dq=fake%20floating%20point%20with%20struct&source=bl&ots=H95O0BX7DI&sig=cQxYwgI6mwZpdOvhSEX8BSvE3UU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=35FgU5u2JcifyASboIGgBg&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=fake%20floating%20point%20with%20struct&f=false).